# How to crate cells contain subvectors from logical vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing

For example I have a logial vector in MATLAB:

```matlab
idx1 = [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
```

And I want to get numbers (count each block) of such blocks: `1 1 1`, i.e. such block contain N elements == 1 (N "1"). idx1 - array, and his dimension can be any, for example 3820000.

**How count many blocks (sequences of ones) occur in the entire array `idx1`?**

```matlab
counts_idx = 0;
init_counts_idx = 0;
arr = 0;

for i = 1:length(idx1) -1
for kk = 1 : length(idx1) - 1
    if idx1(kk + 1) == 1 
       init_counts_idx = init_counts_idx + 1;
       arr = init_counts_idx;
    else
       init_counts_idx =  counts_idx;  
    end
    C = {i,arr};
end
end
```

I try to using cells...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the start and end indices of each block by `diff([0 idx1 0])`. Then, use this information to calculate block lengths `Ns`. Finally express the result as a cell array using the function [`C = mat2cell(A,rowDist)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html#d123e867693).

```
idx1 = [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0];
diffs = diff([0 idx1 0]);

% find start index of the blocks
loc = find(diffs == 1);
% calc block lengths by subtracting end - start indices
Ns = find(diffs == -1) - loc;

C = mat2cell([loc' Ns'],ones(size(loc)))

  4×1 cell array

    {[ 4 3]}
    {[ 9 3]}
    {[16 6]}
    {[29 3]}
```

If you are interested only in the number of such blocks, `length(loc)` will give you the answer, it is similar to `bwconncomp(idx1).NumObjects`.

Comment: In principle, the dimension of a cell is also the number of such blocks. This is what you need! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
bwconncomp(idx1).NumObjects
```

See [`bwconncomp()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html)

Comment: I know, that this function add to Image Processing Toolbox, but I can.t this function in matlab installed in my machine... Thanks a lot!